# Firebase server time

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I want to know when is timestamp created in firebase server, ie, when data is retrieved from firebase (`getValue`) or sent to firebase (`setValue`)...

I know we use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to deal with the timestamp, but I do not know how to actually use this method. Hence I am not able to get the timestamp.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` marker is expanded into the current server-side timestamp when it is **written** to the database on the server.

Comment: Ok thank you! Do you have any link where usage of ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is shown? I want to learn how to code about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+ServerValue.TIMESTAMP?